# XSLT How to wrap common tags in different wrapping elements?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, apply-templates

I have a common set of tags that need to be wrapped in different wrapper elements.
Sample input XML is like-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<a>Hello there</a>
<code>FJ-123-99</code>
<isPopular>True</isPopular>
<timestamp>2019-10-17 07:57:23</timestamp>
  <pop>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <about>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </about>
  </pop>
  <classic>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <about>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </about>
  </classic>
  <retro>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <about>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </about>
  </retro>
</catalog>
```

sample output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<a type="primary">Hello there</a>
<typeCode>FJ12399</typeCode>
<isPopular>Y</isPopular>
<timestamp>20191017:075723</timestamp>
  <pop>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <about>
    <organization>Columbia</organization>
    <amount>10.90</amount>
    <releaseTime>1985</releaseTime>
    </about>
  </pop>
  <classic>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <about>
    <organization>CBS Records</organization>
    <amount>9.90</amount>
    <releaseTime>1988</releaseTime>
    </about>
  </classic>
  <retro>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <about>
    <organization>USA</organization>
    <amount>9.90</amount>
    <releaseTime>1982</releaseTime>
    </about>
  </retro>
</catalog>
```

Here, `<title>` `<artist>` and `<about>` are common for main wrappers like `<pop>` `<retro>` and `<classic>` .

My question is that how do I apply these common templates to my main wrappers
I am able to do all the transformations like- converting timestamp, removing hyphens, changing tag name.

Comment: Is the XML sample the input sample or the wanted result sample? Without minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT you have and result you want plus a textual description on how you want to map the input to the result it is hard to help.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thats the sample input XML. My question is how to apply common templates(like mailAddress, author) to the wrapper elements like mathsBook, englishBook, scienceBook? The output XML is same as input XML except some font size and style translations. I need all the tags in output same as input

Answer (score 0):

Start with the identity transformation as the base template i.e.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

That alone would copy everything recursively level by level, but if you add your own templates for the elements or nodes in general you want to transform you should get what you want, i.e. in your case copy/preserve e.g. `mathBooks`, `englishBook` or `scienceBook` and have your templates for e.g. `address` or `author` kick in for the small changes they do; after your edit it appears you want to change the `catalog/a` element for instance to add an attribute so start with the template shown above and add e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="catalog/a">
  <a type="primary">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

With that approach you can add a template for any further change you need to apply to a different node or element.

Comment: thanks for reply @Martin. I am trying the latter approach. So I have my own templates for tags `address` `author` and `bibliography`. Now how can I apply these 3 templates to my main wrappers like `mathBook` `englishBook`

Comment: By including that template I posted.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.I think I messed up with samplexml. I have edited my question again.

Comment: @RIchaSharma, I still think that the approach in the answer is what you need, I have added one sample template to implement one of the change you want to perform (adding an attribute to `catalog/a`), just add more templates for the other changes you want to make to other elements.